# Search array and insert new item to array not working on java swing app

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I seem to be having issues with the search array function in my swing app , I'm not sure as to what is causing this function not to work, it has a try catch in it to say no matching results but that isn't even working. I also have a section where the user could add their own movie to the arrays, this also seems to not be working at all. I think these issues might be related as they both use the array. Can anyone see the problem ?  Thanks in advanced!

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.text.*;

 public class DVD1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
//construct components
JLabel sortPromt= new JLabel("Sort by:");
JComboBox fieldCombo= new JComboBox();
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

//initalize data in arrays
String title[]={"Casablanca", "Citizen Kane", "Singin in the rain", "The wizzard of Oz"};
String studio[]={"Wanner Brothers", "RKO Pictures", "MGM", "MGM"};
String year[]={"1942", "1941", "1952", "1939"};

 //construct an instance of DVD
 public DVD1()
 {
    super("Classic on DVD");
 }
 //create the menu system
 public JMenuBar createMenuBar()
 {
    ///create instance of menu bar
    JMenuBar mnuBar =new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(mnuBar);

    //Construct and Populate the File menu
    JMenu mnuFile = new JMenu("File",true);
        mnuFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        mnuFile.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
        mnuBar.add(mnuFile);

    JMenuItem mnuFileExit =new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mnuFileExit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        mnuFileExit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(1);
        //mnuBar.add(mnuFileExit);
        mnuFile.add(mnuFileExit);
        mnuFileExit.setActionCommand("Exit");
        mnuFileExit.addActionListener(this);

    //construct and pop the edit menu
    JMenu mnuEdit = new JMenu("Edit",true);
        mnuEdit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        mnuEdit.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(0);
        mnuBar.add(mnuEdit);

    JMenuItem mnuEditInsert = new JMenuItem("Insert New DVD");
        mnuEditInsert.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_I);
        mnuEditInsert.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(1);
        mnuEdit.add(mnuEditInsert);
        mnuEditInsert.setActionCommand("Insert");
        mnuEditInsert.addActionListener(this);

    JMenu mnuEditSearch = new JMenu("Search",true);
        mnuEditSearch.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        mnuEditSearch.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        mnuEdit.add(mnuEditSearch);

    JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByTitle =new JMenuItem("By Title");
        mnuEditSearchByTitle.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        mnuEditSearchByTitle.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        mnuEditSearch.add(mnuEditSearchByTitle);
        mnuEditSearchByTitle.setActionCommand("title");
        mnuEditSearchByTitle.addActionListener(this);

    JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByStudio =new JMenuItem("By Studio");
        mnuEditSearchByStudio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        mnuEditSearchByStudio.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        mnuEditSearch.add(mnuEditSearchByStudio);
        mnuEditSearchByStudio.setActionCommand("title");
        mnuEditSearchByStudio.addActionListener(this);

    JMenuItem mnuEditSearchByYear =new JMenuItem("By Year");
        mnuEditSearchByYear.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
        mnuEditSearchByYear.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(3);
        mnuEditSearch.add(mnuEditSearchByYear);
        mnuEditSearchByYear.setActionCommand("title");
        mnuEditSearchByYear.addActionListener(this);

    return mnuBar;
}//End menu contructor

//Create the conetnt pane
public Container createContentPane()
{
    //populate the jcomboBox
    fieldCombo.addItem("Title");
    fieldCombo.addItem("Studio");
    fieldCombo.addItem("Year");
    fieldCombo.addActionListener(this);
    fieldCombo.setToolTipText("Click the drop-down arow to display sort fields");

    //construct and populate the north panel
    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        northPanel.add(sortPromt);
        northPanel.add(fieldCombo);

    //Create the JTextPane  and center Panel
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        setTabsAndStyles(textPane);
        textPane = addTextToTextPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
            scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

    //create container and set attributes
    Container c =  getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        c.add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    return c;

}//end create container method

//method to create thtab stops and set fontstyles
protected void setTabsAndStyles(JTextPane textPane)
{
    //create Tab Stops
    TabStop[] tabs = new TabStop[2];
        tabs[0] = new TabStop(200, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT,TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
        tabs[1] = new TabStop(350, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT,TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
    TabSet tabset = new TabSet(tabs);

    //set tab style
    StyleContext tabStyle = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset=
        tabStyle.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.TabSet,tabset);
    textPane.setParagraphAttributes(aset, false);

    //set Font Style
    Style fontStyle =
        StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);

    Style regular = textPane.addStyle("regular", fontStyle);
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(fontStyle, "sansSerif");

    Style s = textPane .addStyle("italic",regular);
    StyleConstants.setItalic(s,true);

    s = textPane .addStyle("blod",regular);
    StyleConstants.setBold(s,true);

    s = textPane .addStyle("lard",regular);
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(s,16);

}

//method to ad text to textpane
public JTextPane addTextToTextPane()
{
    Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
    try
    {
        //clear previous text
        doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());

        //Insert title
        doc.insertString(0,"Title\tStudio\tYear\n",textPane.getStyle("large"));

        //insert detail
        for(int j=0;j<title.length;j++)
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),title[j] + "\t",textPane.getStyle("bold"));
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),studio[j] + "\t",textPane.getStyle("italic"));
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),year[j] + "\n",textPane.getStyle("regular"));
        }//end loop
    } //end try
    catch (BadLocationException ble)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldnlt Insert Text");
    }//end catch
    return textPane;
}///end addtexttotextpane method

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  String arg = e.getActionCommand();

  //user clicks the sort by combo box
  if(e.getSource() == fieldCombo)
    {
        switch(fieldCombo.getSelectedIndex())
        {
            case 0:
                sort(title);
                break;
            case 1:
                sort(studio);
                break;
            case 2:
                sort(year);
                break;
        }//end swictch
    } //end if

   //user clicks exit on file menu
    if (arg=="Exit")
        System.exit(0);
   //user clicks insert new dvd on edit menu
    if (arg=="insert")
    {
       String newTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the moive's title");
       String newStudio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the studio for" + newTitle);
       String newYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the year for " + newTitle);

        //Enlarge arrays
        title = enlargeArray(title);
        studio = enlargeArray(studio);
        year = enlargeArray(year);

        //add to arrys
        title[title.length-1] = newTitle;
        studio[studio.length-1] = newStudio;
        year[year.length-1] = newYear;

        //call to sort method
        sort(title);
        fieldCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);

    }//end if

    //user clicks title on search submeu
    if(arg=="title")
        search(arg,title);

    //user clicks title on studio submeu
    if(arg=="studio")
        search(arg,studio);

    //user clicks title on year submeu
    if(arg=="year")
        search(arg,year);

}//end of actionPerfomed method

//Method  to enlarge an arry by 1
public String[] enlargeArray(String[]currentArray)
{
    String[]newArray=new String [currentArray.length +1];
    for(int i = 0; i<currentArray.length;i++)
        newArray[i]=currentArray[i];
    return newArray;
}//end enlarg arry method

//method to sort arrays
public void sort(String tempArray[])
{
    //loop to control number of passes
    for(int pass = 1;pass<tempArray.length;pass++)
    {
        for(int element =0 ; element<tempArray.length -1 ;element++)
            if (tempArray[element].compareTo(tempArray[element+1])>0)
            {
                swap(title,element,element+1);
                swap(studio,element, element+1);
                swap(studio,element, element+1);

            }//end if
    }//end of loop
    addTextToTextPane();
}//end of sort method

//method to swap two elements of an array
public void swap(String swapArray[], int first, int second)
{
    String hold;//temp area to hold for swap
    hold = swapArray[first];
    swapArray[first] = swapArray[second];
    swapArray[second] = hold;

} //end swap method

public void search (String searchField, String searchArray[])
{
    try
    {
        Document doc = textPane.getDocument();//assing text to document object
        doc.remove(0,doc.getLength());//clear previous text

        //display colomTitles
        doc.insertString(0,"TITLE\tSTUDIO\tYEAR\n",textPane.getStyle("large"));

        //Prompt users for search data
        String search=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the " + searchField);
        boolean found= false;

        //search arrays
        for (int i=0; i<title.length; i++)
        {
            if(search.compareTo(searchArray[i])==0)
            {
             doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),title[i] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("bold"));
             doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),studio[i] + "\t", textPane.getStyle("italic"));
             doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),year[i] + "\n", textPane.getStyle("regular"));
            }//end if
        }//end for
        if (found = false)
        {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your search produced no results.", "no results found", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         sort(title);
        }//end if
    }//end try
    catch(BadLocationException ble)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't insert text.");
    }//end catch
}//End serach method
//main method executes at runtime
public static void main(String args[])
{
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    DVD1 f =new DVD1();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setJMenuBar(f.createMenuBar());
    f.setContentPane(f.createContentPane());
    f.setSize(600,375);
    f.setVisible(true);
}//end main method



 }//end dvd class
```

Comment: Don't do this: `if(arg=="title")`. Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos: The OP is reporting errors, not asking for a review of working code.  Code Review only reviews working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `If.. else` condition needs to be modified. `==` can only be used to compare literal values in java, literal values means `int, double, float`, etc. But String is an object and object can not be compared using `==`. If you compare objects using `==` it will try to compare the references values to those objects, which will hardly be equal in your case. When using `String` object `equals()` method is used to compare it. If you are using java 7 then you can also you `switch` case for Strings. But for now I am giving you example of using `equals()` method for your code. Change your `ActionPerformed` method to following.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
   String arg = e.getActionCommand();

  //user clicks the sort by combo box
  if(e.getSource() == fieldCombo)
    {
    switch(fieldCombo.getSelectedIndex())
    {
        case 0:
            sort(title);
            break;
        case 1:
            sort(studio);
            break;
        case 2:
            sort(year);
            break;
    }//end swictch
    } //end if

    //user clicks exit on file menu
    if (arg.equals("Exit"))
    System.exit(0);
    //user clicks insert new dvd on edit menu
    if (arg.equals("insert"))
    {
       String newTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the moive's title");
       String newStudio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the studio for" + newTitle);
       String newYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the year for " + newTitle);

        //Enlarge arrays
        title = enlargeArray(title);
        studio = enlargeArray(studio);
        year = enlargeArray(year);

        //add to arrys
        title[title.length-1] = newTitle;
        studio[studio.length-1] = newStudio;
        year[year.length-1] = newYear;

        //call to sort method
        sort(title);
        fieldCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);

    }//end if

    //user clicks title on search submeu
    if(arg.equals("title"))
     search(arg,title);

 //user clicks title on studio submeu
    if(arg.equals("studio"))
        search(arg,studio);

    //user clicks title on year submeu
    if(arg.equals("year"))
        search(arg,year);

}//end of actionPerfomed method
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip I will keep that in mind. I have changed it accordingly. I found the problem with the insert function i had mnuEditInsert.setActionCommand("Insert"); it was meant to be mnuEditInsert.setActionCommand("insert"); ....although that still doesnt solve the search issue